# Passing multiple parameters with Cucumber and Capybara

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara, ui-testing

Hi I need help with Cucumber to Capybara regex match.

So I want to have a Cucumber step below:

```
I should see "10:00, 11:00, 12:00" under "div1"
```

I want to pass in "10:00, 11:00. 12:00". 
In the step I want to do something like:

```
Then /^I should see "([^\"]*)"+ under "([^\"]*)"$/ do | slots, selector_name |
     slots.each do |value|
     end
end
```

So basically I want to pass in comma separated list of strings and in the step definition 
I want to treat this list as a array of strings. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you'd probably want to do is just let the step capture all three times into a single `slots` item (like you are now), and then do this instead:

```
slots.split(", ").each do |value|
  ...
end
```

See this [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/155-beginning-with-cucumber) for an example (it does something similar in its "Given I have articles titled Pizza, Breadsticks" step).